# Serverless - How to share provider config across unrelated services/functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am trying to figure out how to deploy my AWS lambdas using serverless.

I have a bunch of lambdas that are not related, so I would like each one packaged and deployed individually, along with its resources. The only way I figured out to do this so far is by giving each function folder its own serverless.yml file. But... in order to keep it DRY, I would like to have one master template config.yml that I can read the provider info from.

The problem is, it doesn’t work... `sls deploy -v` (with debug var on) doesn’t show me any errors, it just stops after "Excluding development dependencies…"
It creates the zip file, but it doesn’t go any further.
It seems to me that the provider gets set up before the file variable gets interpolated, something like that; is there any way around this?

This is the folder structure

```
lambda
  config.yml
  func1
    serverless.yml
    index.js
    package.json
    node_modules
```

the relevant part of func1/serverless.yml looks like this:

```
provider: ${file(../config.yml):provider}
```

and config.yml looks like this

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 300
  region: us-east-1
  ...and vpc stuff, role, etc...
```

Comment: That should have worked. Have you tried filing a GitHub issue in the `serverless` framework's GitHub project?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, just a link to the issue I brought up in the serverless github repo
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4761